# Is there better way to create a local Github wiki rather than having two .git directories in one directory?

Tags: github

My purpose is to create a github wiki pages for my personal notes.

In order to create my github wiki from a github repo, I have to do the following. I thought there must be a better way to do. If you know it please let me know.

I have a github repo.

```
cd mygithubrepo
```

I create a wiki page or two in github. I then clone the wiki.

```
git clone https://github.com/myname/myreponame.wiki.git
```

Now I have two .git directories. One in the root and one in the myreponame.wiki.

The main page is the following image. It is nothing wrong. But is there any better way to do it?

[image]